# Max disk cache size in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, caching, size

I want to ask what's the maximum size of cache in Google Chrome. I tried to set 2GB by "-disk-cache-size=" in command line, but it decreased to 200 MB (checked in chrome://net-internals/#httpCache). I ultimately need 4GB or more space for cache.

Firefox and IE have 1024 MB limit. Is there any limit for chrome? Why the max size of cache memory were decreased? Is it possible to set unlimited cache memory?

Answer (score 5):

Google chrome stores cache size as a signed integer, so the maximum size is 2147483647 bytes or just under 2gb.

Here is what happens when I set the cache size to 2gb, for reference.

```
[3756:3756:0927/112842:ERROR:command_line_pref_store.cc(115)] The value 2147483648 of disk-cache-size can not be converted to integer, ignoring!
```

Comment: Related [Chromium Issue 516335](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516335)